# Java run 3 threads and show the ID

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to run multiple java threads and show the ID via output. Right now my code only seems to create one Thread and call it multiple times. Please help me find out what the problem is

My classes:

```
public class MyThreads extends Thread {​​


    public void run() {​​

        Thread t = new Thread();

        t.start();

        System.out.println("Running - ID "+t.currentThread().getId());

    }​​
}​​


public class MyClass {​​
    public static void main(String[] args) {​​

        MyThreads thread1 = new MyThreads();

        MyThreads thread2 = new MyThreads();

        MyThreads thread3 = new MyThreads();

        thread1.run();

        thread2.run();

        thread3.run();
}​​
```

Comment: Try changing your print to `t.getId()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you were doing was, starting a new Thread in the run method of your "MyThreads" class, and then calling `System.out.println("Running - ID "+t.currentThread().getId());` which would only give you the ID of the main thread, because your run method was executing on the main thread, since it was never started properly as a new thread. This is a tad hard to explain, you should read up more on how to properly invoke and handle java threads.

The below code will achieve what you're looking to do

```
public class MyThreads extends Thread {​​

    @Override
    public void run() {​​
        System.out.println("Running - ID "+Thread.currentThread().getId());

        System.out.println("Running - ID "+this.getId());
    }​​
}​​


public class MyClass {​​
public static void main(String[] args) {​​

    MyThreads thread1 = new MyThreads();

    MyThreads thread2 = new MyThreads();

    MyThreads thread3 = new MyThreads();

    thread1.start();

    thread2.start();

    thread3.start();
}​​
```